# Distribution of commercial front-end for LGPL-licensed console application

Tags: licensing, frontend, lgpl, software-distribution

There's a LGPL-licensed console application. I want to create a commercial GUI front-end for it and distribute it bundled with this console app. Does LGPL license allow that?

Note that I am not using a LGPL-licensed *library*, I am using a stand-alone application.

I tried reading the license itself, but it is still unclear to me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that I am not using a LGPL-licensed *library*, I am using a stand-alone application.

The first L in LGPL stands for Lesser not Library. So it does not play much of a role whether it is a library or a stand-alone application.

LGPL is with weaker copyleft. That means, if you re-distribute that LGPL'ed software in object code (binary) you need to offer the source for it (for that version you distribute).

However it is lesser, meaning that you do not need to put your code under LGPL as well. Take care that your users should be able to tell both applications apart (and replace the one or other part easily).

However if you write GUI frontend, I think this is a pretty standard case, you will create a command-line and then execute the LGPL'ed binary.

Take care that this is from a developers perspective, not from a lawyer. A lawyer would require to see your current application and then could tell you in more detail the whats and whereabouts for your very concrete case.

It's also practical you get in contact with the author of the LGPL'ed software, they might be interested to know which supporting tools exist. As they have choosen the LGPL it's likely they do not expect your software to be under LGPL as well. So if you get in touch with the original authors you can also clarify your issue, albeit I don't think there is one technically.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I know that _L_ stands for _lesser_, I referred to the fact that LGPL license text mostly concerns licensing of libraries.

Comment: It was in the early days of the license, but as the name was misleading this was changed. Normally it does not make much sense to use LGPL for whole applications, that is probably why there are not so many licensed under it, however it is perfectly fine for full applications, too.